# capture php error instead of display

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm using the PHP error_log function as I do not want to display it on the page to the user.

However, I can't figure out how to use the PHP printed error to be logged instead of having to type in my own custom log. Is this possible? What variable do I use?

Right now I am capturing date, file name, and line number only:

```
$err_msg = date('Y-m-d h:i:s') . "," . ??PHP_ERROR?? . "," . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . __LINE__;
error_log($err_msg, 3, /path/to/php_errors.log);
```

Comment: `php.ini` http://us3.php.net//manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: How does this help me? error_log is enabled. I want to log the actual PHP error